# Can GCDS (Google Cloud Directory Sync) trigger a cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam

I would like to run a Google Cloud function that renames the posixAccounts -> {username,homeDirectory} in Google Directory .  I am hoping that it's possible to have the function triggered after a successful run of GCDS. Is this possible?  Is there a better way to have these attributes changed after a GCDS?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a 3rd party LDAP server and to answer your question, it is not possible. Since [GCDS](https://support.google.com/a/answer/106368?hl=en) will only sync from LDAP server to your Google Directory.

But if you are using Google Workspaces Admin, one option is Google's [directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides), you can check this [overview](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1628009?hl=en) also.

This is just a theory as I haven't tested it yet, but you can try to forward Admin audit logs to [Cloud Logging](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4579579?hl=en), and then create a log sink to forward the logs to a Pub/Sub topic, and then trigger the [function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers#events).